# Operator with more than one charecter C#

Tags: c#

I need to make an operator with more than one charecter because I want the code to be more readable and more associative.
For example:

```
public static bool operator !&(bool a, bool b)
    {
        return ((a == true && b == true) || (a == false && b = false));
    }
```

Comment: That's not possible, because it would make code **less** readable.

Comment: what do you mean more that one character?  your operands are `bool`

Comment: How about `return a == b` ?

Comment: Well, it's for my own use and for me it will be more readable..

Comment: You can try extension method instead.

Comment: Is the single `=` in `b = false` intentional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only overload the actual C# operators, it isn't possible to create your own.

The list of overloadable operators is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

C# supports operators() functions only for known operators. This is not possible to create custom operator.

See C# Specification item 14.2.2 Operator overloading:

> The overloadable unary operators are:
> `+ - ! ~ ++ -- true false`
>
> The overloadable binary operators are:
> `+ - * / % & | ^ << >> == != > < >= <=`
>
> Only the operators listed above can be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.

I realize this may not be exactly what you want, and that it is *not* the same as an operator, but I would recommend you use a method instead, if possible - perhaps an extension method:

```
public static bool IsBoolEquivalent(this bool a, bool b)
{
    return ((a == true && b == true) || (a == false && b = false));
}
```

Usage:

```
var myBool = true;
var yourBool = false;

var areTheyEquivalent = myBool.IsBoolEquivalent(yourBool); // returns false
```